# Webhook for facebook messenger bot failing

Tags: php, facebook, bots

I am developing a bot for facebook messenger. I created a test page, a facebook app and WebHook page in php.

I registered the bot to the test page and the result was positive, but if I try to send a message to the page, is doesn't respond, as if unable to contact page.

Here my php script:

```
$access_token = "EAAY...ZD";
$verify_token = "verifica_token";
$hub_verify_token = null;

if(isset($_REQUEST['hub_challenge'])) {
    $challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
    $hub_verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];
}


if ($hub_verify_token === $verify_token) {
    echo $challenge;
}


// handle bot's anwser
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$senderId = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$messageText = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
$answer = "I don't understand. Ask me 'hi'.";
if($messageText == "hi") {
    $answer = "Hello";
}
$response = [
    'recipient' => [ 'id' => $senderId ],
    'message' => [ 'text' => $answer ]
];
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='.$access_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($response));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code below independently before you combine them all together.

```php
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=EAAY...ZD",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n    recipient: {id:".$senderId."},\n    message: {text: \"".$answer."\"}\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: hi @iownthegame, I tried this code with this variable:

$senderId = 100000061458447    // should my facebook id

when I run my returns this error:

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Invalid fbid.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"HKdGEATQe78"}}

Comment: Hey you cannot try with your fbid, you should try with the one that your bot received when you send message to the bot

Comment: ok, but when I write a message to the bot, the WebHook does not receive any messages.

Comment: I tried to create a new record in a database whenever the WebHook is called, but when I send a message to the bot, no new record is created

Comment: then you need to go back to check the webhook is verified and you should receive message.

Comment: the WebHook is checked but still does not respond to messages @iownthegame

Comment: it's weird.... I have no idea because I don't use php to write the bot, try https://github.com/pimax/fb-messenger-php-example/blob/master/index.php

Comment: nothing to do, I hope there are more detailed guides in the future, thanks anyway @iownthegame